# Ошибка при вставке: 7 values for 8 columns sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть код который вставлял запись В БД

```
def insertMult(connect,array):
    connect.execute("INSERT INTO Goods (Gtin,Length,Width,Height,Weight,Multuplicator,Gtin2) \
        VALUES ("+array[0]+","+array[1]+","+array[2]+","+array[3]+","+ array[4]+","+array[6]+","+array[7]+")");
    connect.commit()
```

Все было ок, теперь появилась потребность в `Id auto - increment`

Добавил поле в БД с Id. Запускаю код и получаю ексепшн..

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: Goods.Id
```

Изменил код на:

```
def insertMult(connect,array):
    connect.execute("INSERT INTO Goods (Id,Gtin,Length,Width,Height,Weight,Multuplicator,Gtin2) \
        VALUES ("+array[0]+","+array[1]+","+array[2]+","+array[3]+","+ array[4]+","+array[6]+","+array[7]+")");
    connect.commit()
```

Теперь вставка 7 значений в 8 стобцов таблицы, так как `Id auto increment`
ничего не передаю и та же ошибка... Передал - также 8 значений, та же ошибка...
Помогите, плз!

Answer (score 4):

я бы делал это немного по-другому:

```
def insertMult(connect,array):
    connect.execute("INSERT INTO Goods (Gtin,Length,Width,Height,Weight,Multuplicator,Gtin2) \
                     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", array)
```

array - должен содержать ровно 7 переменных с правильными типами данных - типы данных должны соответствовать таковым в таблице

1. если `id` - auto_increment, то это поле не надо явно указывать
2. всегда старайтесь использовать prepared statements/bind variables/parameters при работе с [литералами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) - это убережет вас от SQL injections и будет, скорее всего, быстрее работать, т.к. RDBMS будет использовать уже готовый план выполнения (execution plan) и можно сэкономить на разборе запроса, проверке синтаксиса и привилегий и построении оптимального плана выполнения запроса